# ML Engine training option jobDir was passed to python module with --job-dir option

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

The Google Cloud ML Engine reference says that the training parameter `jobDir` will be passed to TensorFlow program as the `--jobDir` command-line argument.

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#TrainingInput.FIELDS.job_dir

However, Cloud ML Engine passed the path via `--job-dir` command-line argument according to cloud logging.

Which is the intended behavior?
Personally, I prefer the behavior based on the reference (pass via `--jobDir` option). I usually use `tf.flags` module to parse command-line options and `tf.flags` cannot handle correctly this form of options (hyphen delimited option).

Regarads,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect in this case. We will correct it. `tf.flags` appears to support hyphenated arguments by converting the hyphens to underscores:

```
>>> tf.flags.DEFINE_integer('--x-y', 10, '')
>>> def main(argv):
...   print tf.flags.FLAGS.x_y
... 
>>> tf.app.run()
10
```

Comment: But now I have encountered the error with runtime_version=1.5. 

tf.flags.FLAGS.job_dir
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py", line 470, in __getattr__
      raise AttributeError(name)
  AttributeError: job_dir